# Computer won't start - Boot Up sequence ends with Hardware monitor

Tags: boot, troubleshooting

Sometimes my computer starts fine, sometimes it ends in this:

[image: Black Screen of Death]

I've never seen the whole process of it getting to this screen, so I'm not sure if it goes directly to this or if it gives you a chance to change BIOS settings first. But I am pretty sure it never even starts to load Windows.

Usually if I reboot with the dedicated restart button it will restart into Windows just fine. But today that's not working. Even doing a hard shutdown and starting it up again results in the same screen.

My power supply is one I reused from an old PC. Could it be bogging down and causing the voltages to be low? I don't even know what the voltages should be.

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate
CPU: AMD 965BE 3.4Ghz quad core
Motherboard: Biostar TA-890GXB
RAM: 4GB

Comment: Can you do a DPS self-test on that hard drive to see if the drive is mechanically failing?  If it is, usually the BIOS will complain saying you should back it up - but if the hard drive is losing power, it might be a bad hdd, psu, or mobo.  Do you have the ability to switch out the parts for debugging?  Also, have you checked the boot order in your bios?

Comment: Try unplugging or removing integral hardware and see if you can get it to go beyond this.  Example being.. Unplug HDD and if you get past this, and get a 'no harddrive detected'-like error , then it will help your troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't boot because of an SD card I had inserted via USB card reader. It only causes that problem with one particular SD card. It threw me back to the days when you would get a "non-System disk" error when trying to boot up with a floppy disk still in the drive.

Thanks for the help!